# An object reference is required to access non-static field, method or property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have define the constant on constant.cs file, Please find below code.

```
public const string MessageVryPhone = "xyz";
```

Now I have created the object on my controller and take the value in variable from constant.

```
static MessageDM messageDmObj = new MessageDM();

public string abc= messageDmObj.GetContextualMessage(Helper.Constants.MessageVryPhone);
```

While I put the abc in regular experssion `ErrorMessage` I am getting

> an object reference is required to access non-static field, method or property error.

```
[RegularExpression("^\\([1-9][0-9]{2}\\)[ ][0-9]{3}[ ][-][ ][0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = abc)]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Because `RegularExpression` is an *attribute*. It's created just once, like static fields, so it can't access instance fields. In fact, the attribute is initialized during *compilation* and stored in the IL itself. It becomes part of the type's metadata

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, Please let me know how can i access.

Comment: I already did. Check the duplicate. You *can't* access anything at runtime from an attribute. The attribute is created at *compile time*. You can pass a type and simple values though. `RegexExpressionAttribute` uses this mechanism to load error messages from resources